# pyspark split text with id

Tags: python, apache-spark, split, pyspark, rdd

I have a current RDD data like this

```
DataRDD =    [(0,u'A chunk of text'),(1,u'Test sentence check')]
```

my goal is need to split those text into words while keep id of those sentence

my result would to be like

```
[(0,u'A'),(0,u'chunk'),... ,(1,u'check')]
```

right now  I'm currently try to use flatmap with split()

```
result = DataRDD.flatmap(lambda (id,text):(id,text.split()))
```

but the code is not working should I wrote function to split those text instead of split() directly?

Answer (score 1):

Not working is not very precise description so here is a list of issues:

- `DataRDD` is not a `RDD`. I assume it is just a shortcut but providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always welcome. Also lets follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when it comes to naming convention:

  ```
  data_rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,u'A chunk of text'),(1,u'Test sentence check')])
  ```
- there is no such method as `RDD.flatmap`. Correct method is `RDD.flatMap`:

  ```
  data_rdd.flatMap(...)
  ```
- tuple parameter unpacking has been removed in Python 3. See [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) so following syntax

  ```
  lambda (id,text): ...
  ```

  may be not valid on your platform. If you want to make it portable it should be something like this:

  ```
  lambda kv: (kv[0], kv[1].split())
  ```
- `flatMap` expects an iterable structure. If you use a function like above it will simply flatten a `tuple`.

  ```
  data_rdd.flatMap(lambda kv: (kv[0], kv[1].split())).collect()
  ## [0, ['A', 'chunk', 'of', 'text'], 1, ['Test', 'sentence', 'check']]
  ```

  To make it work you should build an iterable like this:

  ```
  lambda kv: ((kv[0], v) for v in  kv[1].split())
  ```
- finally tasks like this are so common that there is a dedicated `flatMapValues` method:

  ```
  data_rdd.flatMapValues(str.split)
  ```